# Repeating A background with arbitary offset in CSS

Tags: html, css

Well, I am wondering if we can repeat a background with an arbitary offset in CSS ? From that i mean can we "Shift" a tile x and y pixel everytime its rendering it ? The uses cases could be mosiacs, patterns and a lot of stuff, Even isometric tiling can be achieved using so.

For example if i have a tile of 10px x 10px

Each time the tile is repeated i want to shift it 10px from top so what i will achieve is

```
[//]
    [//] 
        [//]
            [//]
```

So is there any existant solution or is Canvas just the way to go ( Do it in canvas and then use it as a background )

Comment: You can use `background-position` in combination with `background-repeat` to achieve offset tiling. I'm not sure that's what you are asking though, do you have a sample image of what you are trying to achieve but not sure how to?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate what you are saying and i am trying to make an ascii art ^_^

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes done ^ now makes esne ?

Comment: You probably need to do it in canvas.

Comment: or rather just use webGL , since i know DOM is not the way to go... making 3d ... webgl sounds much bettar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of CSS3, this can't be done using only CSS styling. Repeated patterns are periodic either in the x (horizontal) direction, y (vertical) direction, both directions simultaneously, or neither (single image).

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#backgrounds